# ruby regex should not capture protocol

Tags: ruby, regex, uri

I am using ruby 1.8.7.

I have following text

```
http://example.com
```

I wrote this regex

```
http:\/\/(.*).com
```

This works.

Now I got following text

```
git://example.com
```

In order to make it work I chaged my regex to

```
(http|git):\/\/(.*).com
```

Above code works but I have no use for 'http' or 'git' . It seems I am asking regex to capture something that I am not going to use.

Is there a politer version of this regex where regex will not be capturing protocol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `(?:http|git)` for a non-capturing group.

Comment: just read up on non-capturing group. That's what I was looking for. In 2 minutes I will mark this one as the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regular expression for URIs. Use the URI library instead.

Comment: Or, Addressable::URI. I find Addressable more full-featured while URI is lighter-weight.

Answer (score 0):

Since the protocol seems to be only letters, why not match it with `[a-z]`?

I don't use regex that much, but maybe this will work:

```
[a-z]*:\/\/(.*).com
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `.` before `com` is meant to be literally `.`, you should change it to `\.`.